# Can not catch the exception( Multipart Mime part file exceeds max filesize)

Tags: spring-boot

My springboot version is 2.0.2, And I create the global Exception in the controller class, likes :

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseBody
public Result handleException(Exception e, HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) {
    LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
```

But I could not catch the exception, it seems I should catch the exception before controller, How?

> org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 400: Unable to parse form
>   content
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameters(Request.java:390)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1025)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:75)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
>   ~[jetty-security-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531) ~[jetty-server-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
>   ~[jetty-io-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
>   ~[jetty-io-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
>   ~[jetty-io-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:132)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:760)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:678)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_131]
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multipart Mime part file exceeds max filesize
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiPartInputStreamParser$MultiPart.write(MultiPartInputStreamParser.java:174)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiPartInputStreamParser.parse(MultiPartInputStreamParser.java:812)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiPartInputStreamParser.getParts(MultiPartInputStreamParser.java:493)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.MultiParts$MultiPartsUtilParser.(MultiParts.java:121)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.newMultiParts(Request.java:2410)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParts(Request.java:2333) ~[jetty-server-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractContentParameters(Request.java:479)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameters(Request.java:386)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.10.v20180503.jar:9.4.10.v20180503]
>         ... 35 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use a `ControllerAdvice`. Have a look at the following example:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<String> handle(MaxUploadSizeExceededException ex) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can 
 let the controller extend from `HandlerExceptionResolver`, if you have a view oriented controller. Please have a look at the following example:

```
@Controller
public class MyController implements HandlerExceptionResolver {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView someMethod(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception{
        return new ModelAndView("success");
    }

    @Override
    public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o, Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof MaxUploadSizeExceededException){
            return new ModelAndView("sizeLimitExceeded");
        }
        return new ModelAndView("otherException");
    }
}
```

Comment: You provide two solutions, but all failed.I can not catch the exception :

Comment: Both solutions worked for me. It must be something different in your code interfering.

Comment: Yeah,I success.Thank you very much!